# unicode character cannot be converted to cp1252

Tags: qt, unicode, utf-8

I am writing a QT5 application (with QT Creator) which uses special characters like zodiac signs. This code works perfectly fine on Linux Mint 14:

QString s = QString::fromUtf8("\u2648");

But when I compile it on Windows XP SP3 get a compiler warning which says that the current codepage is cp1252 and the character \u2648 cannot be converted. When I run the program this character is displayed as a question mark.

According to my system settings UTF8(codepage 65001) is installed on my Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note, I have not tried this, and I don't know which compiler you are using, and am completely unfamiliar with QT, so I could be wrong. The following is based on general knowledge about Unicode on Windows.)

On Windows, 8-bit strings are generally assumed to be in the current codepage of the system (also called the "ANSI" codepage). This is **never** UTF-8. On your system, it's apparently cp1252. So there are actually two things going wrong:

1. You are specifying a Unicode character, which the compiler tries to covert to the correct codepage. On Windows, this results in a compile time error, because cp1252 doesn't have a code point to represent u+2648.
2. But assuming that the code would compile, it would still not work. You pass this string, which would be in in cp1251 to fromUtf8, which wants a UTF-8 string. As the string is not valid UTF-8, this would likely result in a runtime error.

On your Linux system, both works "by accident", because it uses UTF-8 for 8-bit strings.

To get this right, specify the 8-bit string in UTF-8 right away:

```
QString s = QString::fromUtf8("\xE2\x99\x88");
```

Comment: The 0 in front of the x creates an empty (or non visible) string. If I change your code to "\xE2\x99\x88" I get a square sign. Also if I use 89 instead of 88 or other numbers. At least I don't get any compiler warnings.

Comment: Sorry, these 0's don't belong there. I removed them.

Comment: I have tried to use: wchar_t a[] = L"\u01FF"; and convert this type to a QString which gives a strange 'o' charakter. But this seems to be the highest possible number. If I use higher numbers  I get a square again.

Comment: Squares usually mean that the corresponding font doesn't have a glyph for the given character (and none of the 3 or four font replacement mechanisms in Windows didn't have a suitable glyph either...). Maybe you need to choose another font.

Comment: Interesting hint - Sans Serif on my Linux does not seem to be the same like MS Sans Serif on Windows.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have found a font which supports the characters I need. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Here is my advice to get everithing work fine:

1. There is only one encoding type UTF-8! Use it everywhere if possible. So, in QtCreator settings set default codepage for sources UTF-8.
2. You can convert your source code in QtCreator: edit -> choose encoding and there reload in codepage. If it can't be done, use linux console application `iconv` this way:

   > iconv -f cp1252 -t utf-8 your_source_in_cp1251.cpp > your_source_in_utf8.cpp
3. I use this code snippet for C-strings in my source codes: in `main.cpp` add `#include <QTextCodec>`, and then do:

```cpp
// For correct encoding
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(codec);
```

Comment: I have tried all your suggestions but it still does not work. Also setCodecForCStrings is not available in QT5.0